# ¿Por que me sale este error al instalar la libreria reportlab en django 1.11?

Tags: python, django

quiero usar lo que es la libreria Reportlab en django, pero me sale un error al tratar de instalarlo
uso el comando    pip install reportlab   por que esto desarollando en un entorno windows.
Pero este error sale en cuanto esta instalando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me puede decir, ¿a que se debe este error ?

Comment: En la pantalla de comando claramente te muestra que actualices la version `pip` a 10.0.1 que esta disponible :)

Comment: Problemas de conexión a Internet o tal vez algún firewall que esté bloqueando algo.

Comment: La excepción es clara `ReadTimeOutError` coincido con César, revisa temas de conectividad, el otro mensaje es un warning para que actualices `pip` y lo puedes obviar por ahora.

Comment: Ahh Y por favor, no pegues imágenes sino que copia directamente el texto del error, va a ser más fácil para ti y mucho más útil para los demás. Saludos.

Comment: respondiendo al mensaje de las imagenes, pues no se podia copiar del cmd ademas no es codigo que yo alla elaborado y solo criticaste asi q ni siquiera me fuiste de ayuda

Comment: Y agradecer a César porque ese fue el error al parecer, desactive mi firewall y descargo con normalidad la librería, gracias a los demás q me ayudaron brindándome posibles soluciones alternativas gracias